# how to assign a css class to title of svg element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have used this: That does not work.
I have added both of urs suggestion.. but it did not work!

```
svg
{
 width:720px;
 height:50px;
 border:#999999 solid 2px;
}
.tooltip{
display: inline;
position: relative;
}
.tooltip:hover:after{
background: #8B8386;
border-radius: 5px;
top:21px;
color: #fff;
content: attr(title);
left: 20%;
padding: 5px 15px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 98;
width: 220px;
font-family:calibri;
font-weight:700
}
</style>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td><div id="first" style="padding:2px">Machine:</div></td>

    <td><div id="second"><svg id="mySVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" ></svg></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
    var data = [  
    {   
        "srno" : 1 ,
        "status" : "Breakdown" , 
        "duration" : 100,
        "color" : "#CC0000",
        "start_time": 0,
        "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 \nstatus:Break down \nDuration:100"  
    },
    {
        "srno" : 2 ,
        "status" : "Mold-Change" , 
        "duration" :70 ,
        "color" : "#FF8000",
        "start_time": 100,
        "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 \nstatus:Break down \nDuration:100" 
    }
    ] ;
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

for ( var i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++){
<!--Drawing Rectangle-->
var rect = document.createElementNS(svgNS,'rect');

var width = data [i].duration ;

rect.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time);
rect.setAttribute('y',0);
rect.setAttribute('width',data[i].duration);
rect.setAttribute('height',50);
rect.setAttribute('fill',data[i].color);

document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(rect);
<!--End of Rectangle-->

<!--Drawing Status on rect-->
var status = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
status.setAttribute('x',data[i].start_time+2);
status.setAttribute('y', '25');
status.setAttribute('fill', '#fff');
status.textContent = data[i].status;

document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(status);
<!--Drawing Status on rect-->

<!--Drawing Tooltip on rect-->
var textWrapper = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'foreignObject');
textWrapper.setAttribute('x', data[i].start_time);
textWrapper.setAttribute('y', '0');
textWrapper.setAttribute('width', data[i].duration);
textWrapper.setAttribute('height', 50);

var text = document.createElement("P");
text.setAttribute('title', data[i].tooltip);
text.style.height = "50px";
textWrapper.appendChild(text);

var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
title.textContent = data[i].title;
title.classList.add('.tooltip');
 rect.appendChild(title);

document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(textWrapper);

<!--Drawing Tooltip on rect-->

}
};
</script>
```

Please suggest to give style to title.I have used this: That does not work.
I have added both of urs suggestion.. but it did not work!

Comment: does not work means? any error? check your browser console..

Comment: It looks like default tooltip, That css is not applied on the the title..

Comment: oho..could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: @Lal please check the code.

Comment: @Lal no error in browser console

Comment: use setAttribute, as in `title.setAttribute('class', 'tooltip');` see https://jsfiddle.net/sandraqu/gcn5r308/1/

Answer (score 1):

1. This element has not been inserted in the DOM so you cannot use `document.getElementByTagName('title')`
2. `document.getElementByTagName('title')[0]` returns the `title` tag of the document which is used to specify the title of the document/page.

**What you should do is this:**

```js
var title = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'title');
title.textContent = data[i].title;//JSON object That works
title.setAttribute('class','tooltip');
```

Assign the attribute on the reference of the element you just created i.e. **title** and not `document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]`

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work?@bhavya_w and @Guruprasad Rao

Comment: Guruprasad said the same@bhavya_w, but the option you suggested is not working

Comment: @sia.. I'll look into your issue and hopefully find the solution but can you tell me what you are trying to achieve here ( the bigger picture )...?

Comment: Tooltip to svg element that to having the css defined..@bhavya_w

Comment: Please convey if it is not possble@bhavya_w

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as below:

```
title.classList.add("tooltip");
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vmfksf6t/1/)**

**UPDATE:**

Check this **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/o8n6urpt/)**

There were some console errors which I have cleared.

Just copy and paste the `javascript` part as it is in your page and see that class will be added now. One major change was that you were adding class to title along with `.` like `title.classList.add('.tooltip');` but it should have been without `.` like `title.classList.add('tooltip');` Check the demo and let me know!!

Comment: I have assigned this title to svg element, is that the reason for not showing up?@Guruprasad Rao

Comment: Nothing like that! You can easily manipulate it!! Right now what is the problem? Isn't the `className` not getting assigned??

Comment: It displays default one with no effects.@Guruprasad Rao

Comment: Did you check the demo!! Check the `console` to see the element!! Or else you need to post complete detail to the problem saying like how you are attaching your `title` element!!

Comment: That's why I said, I need more detail on your code!! so it will be good if you post the complete code or replicate the problem you are facing!! :)

Comment: @sia.. Check the code now!! and updated demo too.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the efforts! but still i could see the same by default tooltip. Is it browser problem?

Comment: I saw lots of examples in which when I executed the code from dreamweaver, tooltip was not showing up, while they were visible in online execution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77203/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-sia).