# How to dynamically generate id and give it to particular elements in html SVG using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

In this code I have 4 rectangles and will need to draw more.
Instead of writing single line more times can't we generate id for lets say in this example for  and use loop for it?

```
<style>
.tooltip {
text-decoration:none;
position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
display:none; 
}
.tooltip:hover span {
display:block;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
width:70;
height:50;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 5px 15px;
background-color:#999999;
color:#CCCCCC;
font-family:calibri;
font-weight:700;
border:#777 solid 2px;
}

</style>

<div class="tooltip" style="width:100px; height:90px; background-    color:orchid; text-align:center">
Rect1
<span id="tooltip-span">
    Hello! I am<br/>
    Rect1!!!!!
</span>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="tooltip" style="width:100px; height:90px; background-color:Green; text-align:center">
Rect2
<span id="tooltip-span1">
    Hello! I am<br/>
    Rect2!!!!!
</span>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="tooltip" style="width:100px; height:90px; background-color:Orange; text-align:center">
Rect3
<span id="tooltip-span2">
    Hello! I am<br/>
    Rect3!!!!!
</span>
</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<div class="tooltip" style="width:100px; height:90px; background-color:Skyblue; text-align:center">
Rect4
<span id="tooltip-span3">
    Hello! I am<br/>
    Rect4!!!!!
</span>
</div>
<script>
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');
//I want these all to generate dynamically
var tooltipSpan1 = document.getElementById('tooltip-span1'); 
var tooltipSpan2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-span2');
var tooltipSpan3 = document.getElementById('tooltip-span3');
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
var x = e.clientX,
    y = e.clientY;
 //Can we write these lines in any of loop
 //after we could generate id dynamically?
tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px'; 
tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan1.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan1.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan2.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan2.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan3.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
tooltipSpan3.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
</script>
```

And finally avoiding same statements multitime?
Please suggest any reference book or links to get more information about it?

Comment: You might want to have an array of javascript objects (each tooltipSpan would be an object). Then you could iterate through all your tooltipSpans. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) for documentation.

Comment: @Jeft.. yes  I do, and what if I want to generate id?

Comment: Where should the ids come from? Do you meen to extract them from the DOM? That could be done by selecting all elements that have the class "tooltip" and reference to it's child. A better way would be to already create the tooltips dynamicly (from the array of objects).

Comment: Yes you can see the same class in the code..just edited@Jeft.Like span id, and the content in it (to be shown as tooltip). I have a great problem with it. I used libraries for it but they dont appear(tooltip)!

Comment: But the question is where the initial data comes from to create your tooltips. That is where you should get the ids from.

Comment: (how to assign a css class to title of svg element using javascript?)-In this question, I have JSON object already, And I am trying new method mentioned above , to implement in old question?

Comment: How does that js-object look like? How are the spans generatad?

Comment: I have assigned right now in the program above in each and every div!

Comment: You can see that question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093755/how-to-assign-a-css-class-to-title-of-svg-element-using-javascript/30094249?noredirect=1#comment48343450_30094249)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array like that:

```
var data = [  
{   
    "srno" : 1 ,
    "status" : "Breakdown" , 
    "duration" : 100,
    "color" : "#CC0000",
    "start_time": 0,
    "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 \nstatus:Break down \nDuration:100"  
},
{
    "srno" : 2 ,
    "status" : "Mold-Change" , 
    "duration" :70 ,
    "color" : "#FF8000",
    "start_time": 100,
    "tooltip": "Show up: 12:30 \nstatus:Break down \nDuration:100" 
}
] ;
```

you would make a function that does whatever you want with each object, in your case set top & left:

```
function setXY (item, x, y) {
          item.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px'; 
          item.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
}
```

this function would then - in your case - be called like that:

```
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
   var x = e.clientX,
   var y = e.clientY;
   // iterate through all your tooltips in your data-array
   for (tip in data) {
       var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span'+tip.srno);
       if(tooltipSpan) {  // just make sure you actually got a valid DOM-Object
           setXY(tooltipSpan, x, y);
       }
   }
}
```

**BUT:** 
Rethink if you really want do this on EVERY mouse move! 
It might be sufficiant to position the tooltips statically according to the hovering divs in your css like:

```
.tooltip:hover span {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;  // changed from fixed to absolute!
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for easiest solution!!!@Jeft, Can I ask you one more problem? like why you have used item for? and how the tooltip will get the content of tooltip named(in JSON object for itle to show on it)

Comment: You're welcome! You might want to accept the answer, if it solved your problem. If the problem is connected to this go ahead! If it's a different problem you maybe should ask a new question.

Comment: Please tell me what will be the next statement to this `var text = document.createElement("P");` so that it wil assign id like we retrieve: `id="tooltip-span1"` and for You have used `var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span'+tip.srno);`

Comment: `text.setAttribute("id", "tooltip-span"+tip.srno);`  is it the same to be used?

Comment: yes, or `text.id = 'tooltip-span'+tip.srno;`  but this assumes you are in the same kind of loop: `for (tip in data) { .... }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method of doing what you want that would also save you the work of having to write out each `span` individually.

First you need to give each `div` a data attribute to hold the text to appear in its tooltip, like so:

```
<div data-tooltip="This is a tooltip"></div>
```

And then use the following JavaScript:

```
var divs=document.querySelectorAll("[data-tooltip]"),span=document.createElement("span"),x=divs.length,div;
while(x--){
    div=divs[x];
    div.appendChild(span.cloneNode(0))
    div.lastChild.id="tooltip-"+x;
    div.lastChild.innerHTML=div.dataset.tooltip;
    div.addEventListener("mousemove",function(event){
        var left=event.clientX,top=event.clientY;
        this.lastChild.style.top=(top+20)+"px";
        this.lastChild.style.left=(left+20)+"px";
    },0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks shaggy! I want you to see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30093755/how-to-assign-a-css-class-to-title-of-svg-element-using-javascript/30094249?noredirect=1#comment48343450_30094249) why I am implementing this..